# Postgres equivalent of Oracle's VARCHAR2(N CHAR)?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

We are in the process of migrating our existing Oracle database to Postgres. So far I have found that both `VARCHAR2` and `NUMBER` are not compatible, but have equivalents in `VARCHAR` and `NUMERIC` respectively.

However in our schema I can also see we are defining some datatypes using `VARCHAR2(31 CHAR)`. Changing this to `VARCHAR(31 CHAR)` is not compatible with Postgres, as it gives a syntax error on the CHAR part. Is there an equivalent way to define this using Postgres 12?

Comment: Do you want a particular character set in the `VARCHAR2(31 CHAR)` column? (or do you just want to make sure each char is represented by a single byte). In short is this a character   encoding requirement, or a database sizing requirement?

Comment: I believe given that we are using `VARCHAR2(31 CHAR)` that we need to maintain the character limit of 31, so it is a sizing requirement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Postgres doesn't make a distinction between "char length" and "byte length" when declaring the maximum length of a `varchar` column.

The limit is **always** specified as the number of *characters*.

So the equivalent of Oracle's `VARCHAR2(31 CHAR)` is `VARCHAR(31)` in Postgres.

There is however, no equivalent for Oracle's `VARCHAR2(31 byte)`.

Comment: Ok thanks very much. I've actually noticed we do have examples of `VARCHAR2(31 byte)` in the schema as well. In this case, do we simply just need to remove the reference to `byte`, and have the length defined in characters? I can't see any harm in that as there's no risk of the size being reduced this way, is that correct?